# What is the quickest/most efficient way to find the first occurrence index of an object in an list with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, at some point the key "a" is populated and continues to be populated for all subsequent objects in the array. What is the fastest and most efficient way to get to that index?

```
: [{a:null,),{a:null,..},{a:"Value",..},,{a:"Value",..}]
```

My current method is:

```
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
   if(list[i].a)
      return i;
}
return null;
```

What is the fastest/smartest way to locate the index where "a" is not null? Is there a better way to do this? Ideal performance should be for lists with large numbers of objects (i.e. thousands of objects).

Comment: That's really not that bad... just verbose.

Comment: its be more efficient to cache out the list length.

Comment: I'd be surprised if it wasn't cached by the JS engine.

Comment: @jmar777 how to unverbose it?

Comment: @DaveNewton Depends what you mean. It's not like it repeats an O(n) operation every time, but the `for` loop itself doesn't cache the value.  It still does a property lookup on the array each iteration.

Comment: @jmar777 I'd still expect that would depend on the JS engine; inlining stuff like that is compiler/JIT 101.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the fastest and most efficient way to get to that index?

With regards to efficiency, you're already pretty close to as best as you're going to get.  `for` loops are fast, and you're already breaking out of the iteration once you find a match, which is about all you could hope for.

As mentioned in the comments, however, you *could* cache the `.length` value, which is *technically* faster, but is the very definition of premature/mico-optimization.  Just for the sake of thoroughness, though, that would look something like this:

```
for(var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
    if(list[i].a) return i;
}
return null;
```

I mentioned earlier in the comments that this approach was "really not that bad... just verbose.", and you asked if it could be "unverbose[d]" (great word, by the way :)).  TBH, I don't think there are any especially great ways of doing that.  There aren't any built-in "functional" approaches (e.g., `forEach()`, `filter()`, etc.) that allow breaking out early, and `indexOf()` doesn't support this kind of a comparison test.

About the best I can offer is some sort of hope for the future here.  ES6 introduces the [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method, which when combined with [ES6 fat-arrow functions](http://www.2ality.com/2012/04/arrow-functions.html) will allow for something like this:

```
var idx = list.findIndex(item => item.a !== null);
```

Until then, we basically just have `for` loops (or I suppose `while` loops, with no real advantage). :\

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to do this better/faster, and they both bypass your question.

In the first case, you store a variable that tells you what your first value is; you can do this either when the value is initialized to a non-null, or after the first walk-through to save yourself future walkthroughs.

In the second case, you never initialize the null values of your array and the zeroeth element is always the element you want.